# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]

Tags: pgfplots, memory

I am trying to plot a load displacement curve using pgfplots. I am getting the following error message. 
"TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]"

I am trying to find a solution to this problem. please help. Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every mark/.append style={mark size=1pt}]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=25, ymin=0, ymax=200, width = 8cm, height = 7cm, xtick align =inside, ytick align =inside, ytick distance=40, xtick distance =5, minor x tick num={1}, minor y tick num={1}, xlabel = True strain, ylabel= {True stress (MPa)}, legend style= {nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}, legend pos= north east, legend cell align={left}}, y tick label style = {/pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={}, set decimal separator={.}, fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd}]
         \addplot[black, sharp plot, mark=none] table [x=a, y=b]{L_D_9C.txt};\addlegendentry{9C};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the content of `L_D_9C.txt`?

Comment: Hi Teepeemm, I am comparatively new to this forum and was wondering how to attach the text file. couldn't find any option to attach the file

Comment: @Tasnuva Just paste it as text, the same way you have pasted your LaTeX document.

Comment: You can add the text file to your MWE (provided it is not overly long) by sandwiching it between `\begin{filecontents}{L_D_9C.txt} ` and `\end{filecontents}`.

Comment: And if it is overly long, try to figure out which parts of the document you need to get the error to occur, and paste just that.

Comment: thanks everyone. the file is way too long to paste and latex is also complaining for that and the error message is related to that.

Comment: try `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` to build the PDF

Comment: Hi AlexG, I tried Lualatex, but thats giving an error too :(